# Possible to push applications instead of Docker images with Cloud Foundry + Diego?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm exploring Cloud Foundry and its Docker support with Diego. My questions are: is it possible to deploy a jar as before (with `cf push`, providing information about the jar location, the buildpack and stack to use) and have CF build a (Docker?) container from it just as it used to do with DEA, or is it necessary to always provide a ready-made Docker image for CF to build containers from? If the 'old' way is still supported, is it a good idea to use Diego this way, or should we all move towards Docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Foundry's Diego runtime continues to support buildpack deployments, where it will create the container and the runtime artifacts needed to run your application. The container it creates is not a Docker container. For example, Pivotal Cloud Foundry creates a Garden-RunC container.

Docker support can be useful when you have a prepackaged Docker image that you would like to deploy without modification, but the buildpack approach is still preferred when you have a choice.

Buildpacks will simplify the role of both the developer and the IT operator when using Cloud Foundry. With buildpacks, the developer is no longer responsible for design and maintenance of the Dockerfile, and other concerns that are not directly related to application development.

The IT operator gets complete consistency in terms of versioning and patch levels for the OS and runtimes across all buildpack containers. They also have the ability to perform automated, zero-downtime patches and upgrades that are deployed across all buildpack containers in the Cloud Foundry environment. This is a very powerful tool, both for security and efficiency.